# Trigger a form update in Gravity Forms after jQuery change to hidden field

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

IN SHORT: Is there a javascript function or hook to trigger an update to a Gravity Form so that the conditional logic is executed?

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

I'm using Gravity Forms and I have created an "on change" event

```
$('#gform_1').find('.gfield_date_dropdown_month select').change(function () {
      var month = $(this).val();
      $('input#input_1_6').val(month).change();
});
```

After this event I would like Gravity Forms to check/update the form so that the "Conditional Logic" is being executed to related fields.

I have checked the hooks on https://docs.gravityforms.com/category/extending-gravity-forms/hooks/javascript
but I can't find a hook that I can use for this purpose. Any ideas?

UPDATE:
The field that is changed (#input_1_6) is "hidden". This seems to be the problem. When I make this field visible it does work! So a change to a "hidden" field does not seem to trigger the update to the form. If I would have a function that would trigger this update I could add it to my jQuery function.

---

Some background information on this issue. I want a field to become visible when a certain month is selected in a date field. Since Gravity Forms does not support  "Conditional Logic" based on a date field I want to update a hidden field with the "month value" and then use that value for the "Conditional Logic" on a related field.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Gravity Forms conditionals are triggered with the `click` or `change` events, depending on the type of field. You can manually trigger the `change` event with the `.change()` method.

Note this isn't working because the conditional isn't tied to the field you attached a change event to, so you have to trigger `.change()` on the field that *does* have conditionals. Assuming field `1_6` is the field that triggers conditionals:

```
$('#gform_1').find('.gfield_date_dropdown_month select').on('change', function(){
    var month = $(this).val();
    $('#input_1_6').val(month).change();
});
```

Some other small notes, consider using `.on('change', function(){}` instead of `.change(function(){}` as it will trigger on dynamic elements - as well as you don't need `input` before `#input_1_6` since it's already a unique element.

Cheers!

Comment: @Xhunk Thanks. I have copied your code but the conditional is still not being triggered. You can see it here: http://frsurf.com/test-page/ . I do see that the conditional works after submitting the form with a value in #input_1_6 so the conditional does seem to be set correctly. But is just doesnt update "live". What do you think?

Comment: Are you sure the conditional is set up correctly? I tried changing the value of the field manually and it still wasn't showing the fields

Comment: Yes. You can change the month and submit. You will see an new field appear. Try January and December

Comment: Do you see the other field appear when the page reloads?

Comment: Yes. Can you share a screenshot of the conditional in the admin?

Comment: OK, I have added the screenshot to my original question.
BTW. there was a field called "Number" but that was obsolete so I removed it.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure - I can't get the conditional logic to trigger normally like it should either

Answer (score 0):

Gravity Forms's conditional logic can also be triggered with vanilla JS by sending the input element an "input" event after changing its value:

```
input_element.value = '9001';
input_element.dispatchEvent((new Event('input', {'bubbles': true})));
```