# Show currently selected product variation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, gravityforms

I have this gravity forms code in my functions php file.
I would like to replace the word "BOOM" with the currently selected product variation name on my woocommerce product page.

This should then populate the Gravity form field with the current product variation name .

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_value_your_parameter', 'my_custom_population_function' );
function my_custom_population_function($value) {
return 'BOOM';
}
```

Comment: Not possible as variation selection is a client side live event that comes after php server side…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec You could leave the field empty and populate it via an AJAX call, correct?

Comment: Yes javascript + Ajax is the only way…

Comment: I have tried this but then the gravity form will not update.

Comment: I have used java script to and the correct value is been updated in the gravity form but the form will not update on change of the value or when the field is first populated. Its killing me

Comment: Can you edit your question so it also contains the HTML structure of your form?

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested I used the following....

https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-get-currently-selected-variation-id/

together with this JS

[Trigger a form update in Gravity Forms after jQuery change to hidden field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50974335/trigger-a-form-update-in-gravity-forms-after-jquery-change-to-hidden-field)

The result...

$(function() {

```
$('input.variation_id').change(function() {
    var var_per = $('input.variation_id').val();
  $('#input_12_27').val(var_per).change();
});
```

});